# How many elements from one list are present in the other list

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I can't seem to be able to create a function that takes two lists as arguments and returns how many elements there are common in both lists.
e.g. f [1, 2, 4, 2] [2, 3, 4, 4] returning 2 (repetitions are ignored).
Any suggestions? I tried this

```
*Main> a = [1, 2, 3]
*Main> b = [2, 3, 4]
*Main> [x | x <- a, x <- b]
[2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4]
```

Then I was planning to use the length function to know how many item there are in common.

Comment: what did you try? What did not work?

Comment: you could do it with list comprehension: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out

Comment: Just edited it and added what I tried.  The list comprehension is x such that x is in a and x is in b. Not sure why I get this output

Comment: You can't extract the same `x` twice in Haskell. You can, however, extract `y` from the second list and then require `x==y`.

Comment: Thanks, just tried [(x, y) | x <- a, y <- b, x == y] however it doesn't deal with the repetitions. Thanks, I can manage it know

Comment: I think the easiest solution here is using the `Set` type (in `Data.Set`).

Comment: ``length (filter (`elem` a) b)``

Comment: here are the functions you can use:

nub: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub

intersect: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to extract an `x` from both lists; extract from *one* list, and check if it is present in the other.

```
> a = [1,2,3]
> b = [4,3,2]
> [x | x <- a, x `elem` b]
[2,3]
> [x | x <- b, x `elem` a]
[3,2]
```

Note that the order in which items appear in the result depends on the order in which they appear in the list you pull from.

Comment: I don't think this exactly matches what the OP is after. It's fine in the examples you give, but if `a` contains duplicate elements, your function will also duplicate them in the output. (See the example they gave of `f [1, 2, 4, 2] [2, 3, 4, 4] returning 2`.) This is why I suggested using `Set`s. (An alternative would be using your solution alongside `nub`, but I think that is much less efficient if the lists become larger.)